# Why Angular keycloak required-login not redirect?

Tags: angular, keycloak, keycloak-angular

i am integrating angular keycloak 7.3.1 into my application in angular 9
After initializing keycloak I do not go to the keycloak login page.
I don't see any calls starting, neither login, nor token, nor info.
How can I solve this problem?
I don't use a function as in the guide but I integrated keycloak in an ngrx effect, but even following the guide the results were not better

the config:

```
 window.oidcConfig = {
    config: {

      /**
       * URL to the Keycloak server, for example: http://keycloak-server/auth
       */
      url: `${DOMAIN}/auth`,

      /**
       * Name of the realm, for example: 'myrealm'
       */
      realm: 'quake',

      /**
       * Client identifier, example: 'myapp'
       */
      clientId: 'quake',
    },

    initOptions: {
      /**
       * Adds a [cryptographic nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)
       * to verify that the authentication response matches the request.
       * @default true
       */
      useNonce: true,

      /**
       *
       * Allow usage of different types of adapters or a custom adapter to make Keycloak work in different environments.
       *
       * The following options are supported:
       * - `default` - Use default APIs that are available in browsers.
       * - `cordova` - Use a WebView in Cordova.
       * - `cordova-native` - Use Cordova native APIs, this is recommended over `cordova`.
       *
       */
      adapter: 'default',

      /**
       * Specifies an action to do on load.
       * 'login-required'|'check-sso'
       */
      onLoad: 'login-required',

      /**
       * Set an initial value for the token.
       */
      token: '',

      /**
       * Set an initial value for the refresh token.
       */
      refreshToken: '',

      /**
       * Set an initial value for the id token (only together with `token` or
       * `refreshToken`).
       */
      idToken: '',

      /**
       * Set an initial value for skew between local time and Keycloak server in
       * seconds (only together with `token` or `refreshToken`).
       */
      timeSkew: 0,

      /**
       * Set to enable/disable monitoring login state.
       * @default true
       */
      checkLoginIframe: true,

      /**
       * Set the interval to check login state (in seconds).
       * @default 5
       */
      checkLoginIframeInterval: 5,

      /**
       * Set the OpenID Connect response mode to send to Keycloak upon login.
       * @default fragment After successful authentication Keycloak will redirect
       *                   to JavaScript application with OpenID Connect parameters
       *                   added in URL fragment. This is generally safer and
       *                   recommended over query.
       * 'query'|'fragment'
       */
      responseMode: 'fragment',

      /**
       * Specifies a default uri to redirect to after login or logout.
       * This is currently supported for adapter 'cordova-native' and 'default'
       */
      redirectUri: `${DOMAIN}/quake`,

      /**
       * Specifies an uri to redirect to after silent check-sso.
       * Silent check-sso will only happen, when this redirect uri is given and
       * the specified uri is available whithin the application.
       */
      silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.quixConfig.baseUrl + '/assets/silent-check-sso.html',

      /**
       * Specifies whether the silent check-sso should fallback to "non-silent"
       * check-sso when 3rd party cookies are blocked by the browser. Defaults
       * to true.
       */
      silentCheckSsoFallback: false,

      /**
       * Set the OpenID Connect flow.
       * @default standard
       * 'standard'|'implicit'|'hybrid';
       */
      flow: 'standard',

      /**
       * Configures the Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE) method to use.
       * The currently allowed method is 'S256'.
       * If not configured, PKCE will not be used.
       */
      pkceMethod: 'S256',

      /**
       * Enables logging messages from Keycloak to the console.
       * @default false
       */
      enableLogging: true
    },

    /**
     * boolean
     */
    enableBearerInterceptor: true,

    /**
     * boolean
     */
    loadUserProfileAtStartUp: false,

    /**
     * \{url: string;httpMethods?: HttpMethods\}list
     */
    bearerExcludedUrls: [],

    /**
     * string
     */
    authorizationHeaderName: '',

    /**
     * string
     */
    bearerPrefix: '',
  }
```

the service:

```
export class AuthService {
  public config: any
  public authConfig: any

  constructor(
    @Optional() config: QuangAuthConfig,
    private keyCloak: KeycloakService,
    private store: Store<any>,
  ) {
    if (config) {
      this.config = config;
    }
  }

  startAuth() {
    if (_window().oidcConfig) {
      this.authConfig = _window().oidcConfig
    } else if (this.config.oidcConfig) {
      this.authConfig = this.config.oidcConfig
    } else {
      alert('[AUTH SERVICE] No auth config')
    }
    return from(this.keyCloak.init(this.authConfig))
  }

  startAuthAndDispatch() {
    if (_window().oidcConfig) {
      this.authConfig = _window().oidcConfig
    } else if (this.config.oidcConfig) {
      this.authConfig = this.config.oidcConfig
    } else {
      alert('[AUTH SERVICE] No auth config')
    }
    from(this.keyCloak.init(this.authConfig)).subscribe(isLogged => {
      if (isLogged) {
        this.store.dispatch(userLogin({isLogged: isLogged}))
      }
    })
  }

  getUserInfo() {
    return from(this.keyCloak.loadUserProfile())
  }

  getUserInfoAndDispatch() {
    from(this.keyCloak.loadUserProfile()).subscribe((user: any) => {
      this.store.dispatch(userInfoLogin({userData: user}))
    })
  }

  refreshToken() {
    return from(this.keyCloak.updateToken(30))
  }


  logout() {
    return from(this.keyCloak.logout())
  }

  logoutAndDispatch() {
    from(this.keyCloak.logout()).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.store.dispatch(userLogout())
        this.store.dispatch(userInfoLogout())
      }
    )
  }
}
```

the effect

```
export class AuthEffects {

  constructor(
    private actions$: Actions,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
  }

  startAuthEffect$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(ROOT_EFFECTS_INIT),
      exhaustMap(action =>
        this.authService.startAuth().pipe(
          map(is => userLogin({isLogged: is}))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  getInfoUserEffect$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(userLogin),
      exhaustMap(action =>
        this.authService.getUserInfo().pipe(
          map((user: any) => userInfoLogin({userData: user}))
        )
      )
    )
  );

  endAuthEffect$ = createEffect(
    () => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(userLogout),
      exhaustMap(action =>
        this.authService.logout().pipe(
          map(() => userInfoLogout())
        )
      )
    )
  );

}
```

Comment: Solved, you need the exact version of the libraries
check the documentation carefully